# Mouse movement angle in openFrameworks

Tags: mouse, angle, openframeworks

I am currently in the process of creating a sort of drawing program in openFrameworks that needs to calculate the angle of mouse movement. The reason for this is that the program needs to be able to draw brush strokes similar to the way photoshop does it.

I've been able to get it to work in a very jaggy way. I've placed my code in the MouseDragged event in openFrameworks, but the calculated angle is extremely jaggy and not smooth in anyway. It needs to be smooth in order for the drawing part to look good.

```
void testApp::mouseMoved(int x, int y ){
    dxX = x - oldX;
    dxY = y - oldY;

    movementAngle = (atan2(dxY, dxX) * 180.0 / PI);
    double movementAngleRad;
    movementAngleRad = movementAngle * TO_RADIANS;
    if (movementAngle < 0) {
        movementAngle += 360;
    }

    testString = "X: " + ofToString(dxX) + " ,";
    testString += "Y: " + ofToString(dxY) + " ,";
    testString += "movementAngle: " + ofToString(movementAngle);

    oldX = x;
    oldY = y;
}
```

I've tried different ways of optimizing the code to work smooth but alas without results.

If you sit with a brilliant idea on how this could be fixed or optimized, I will be very grateful.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it to some degree by using an ofPolyline object.

The following code shows how it works.

```
void testApp::mouseMoved(int x, int y ){
    float angleRad;
    if (movement.size() > 4)
    { angleRad =  atan2(movement[movement.size()-4].y - y, movement[movement.size()-4].x -x);}
    movementAngle = (angleRad * 180 / PI) + 180;
    movement.addVertex(x,y,0);
}
```

As seen in the code I'm using the point recorded 4 steps back to increase the smoothness of the angle. This works if the mouse is moved in stroke like movements. If the mouse is moved slow, jaggyness will still occur.